# integrating fullcalendar in cakephp, what files to include where?

Tags: php, cakephp, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-3

I'm a bit confused as how to integrate fullcalendar into my app. I want to display weekly routine in the calendar for individual users. I do not need to use the drag and drop or editing events functions. I only need to display events from an existing db. What files should I include in what path of the directory of the app?

Comment: I think you  are searching this https://fullcalendar.io

Comment: yes I am using this plugin but I can't seem to add it properly to my cakephp app

Comment: so you have to share your code what you have tried.Then people can help you.

Comment: I suggest you refer to https://fullcalendar.io/docs/installation